Generating a Composite @Id with Prefix from Enum and Database-Generated Unique Identifier in Spring Boot JPA
I'm currently working on a Java application using Spring Boot and JPA (Hibernate) and facing a unique challenge regarding the generation of composite @Id for my entities. My goal is to create an @Id that is a string, combining a prefix derived from an enum value with a unique identifier that is generated by the database. Specifically, the @Id should start with a unique ID  followed by an enum-based prefix , forming something like "00001-A" for a composite @Id.
Here's a simplified version of my entity setup:
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Enumerated;
import jakarta.persistence.EnumType;

@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    private String compositeId; // This needs to be generated as @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE) + "-" + myEnum.getPrefix(); Example: 00001-A

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private MyEnum myEnum;

    // Other fields and methods...
}


public enum MyEnum {
    TYPE_A("A"),
    TYPE_B("B"),
    TYPE_C("C");

    private final String prefix;

    MyEnum(String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    public String getPrefix() {
        return prefix;
    }
}

My challenge is to automatically generate the compositeId in a way that integrates seamlessly with JPA's lifecycle, combining a database-generated sequence number with the prefix from the MyEnum type. I'm looking for a solution that allows me to prepend the enum-based prefix to the unique identifier generated by the database to form the composite @Id.
I'm aware that JPA might not directly support this composite @Id generation pattern out of the box. I'm considering the use of custom identifier generators (IdentifierGenerator), potentially leveraging @PrePersist or @PostPersist callbacks to set up the compositeId after or before persistence.
However, I'm uncertain about the best approach to achieve this while maintaining a clean and performant application. I'm particularly concerned about how to ensure the uniqueness and integrity of the compositeId throughout the application's lifecycle and across transactions.
Any advice, insights, or examples on how to implement this composite @Id generation pattern in a Spring Boot application using JPA and Hibernate would be greatly appreciated.

One question that comes to mind is whether you need this format for the id in the DB. I.e. do you need 2 columns, composite_id='100001-A' and my_enum='A'? Why not just id=100001 and my_enum='A', where information is not duplicated? And then, you can create the composite id in Java - like String getCompositeId() { return id + "-" + myEnum; }. Second question is whether you really need a sequence to generate the variable part - can't you use a UUID and generate the entire ID yourself?

@NikosParaskevopoulos
Actually, 100001-A is intended to serve as a unique registration number that combines a sequential identifier and a type indicator (A, B, or C) directly in the database. This concatenation is a specific challenge that is proposed to us. The "matricula" attribute needs to be a String and id.

I haven't done this, so I can only speculate: You could query the sequence before inserting the entity (pre-persist looks good) and generate the id manually. I think "select next" from the sequence should be executed in a new transaction. The IdentifierGenerator you mentioned looks good, if you don't mind being tied to Hibernate.
